# Ionic, cordova, phonegap, jquery Bluetooth plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I want to create a mobile app with Ionic. I need a bluetooth plugin that can connect multiple devices regardless of the operating system (can be ios or android).

Does cordova or phonegap or jquery support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several Cordova plugins to manage with bluetooth, see:

http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=bluetooth

For example:

https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle

or

https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial

These plugins are available both for iOS and Android, and as Ionic is based on Cordova you can develop your Ionic app using all Cordova plugins.